# How to find documents if name includes all other documents keywords in mongo or mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection with 2 columns:

```
name: string
keywords: array
```

Some documents like this:

```
{ name: 'foo is good', keywords: ['foo', 'fo', 'fooo'] }
```

When I create a new document with `name='bar is good'`, I want to find documents if name includes all other documents keywords, something like this:

```
  // new document with name='bar is bad'
  { name: 'bar is good', keywords: ['bar', 'bars', 'barr'] } // find this, keywords have 'bar'
  { name: 'baz is good', keywords: ['baz', 'is', 'good'] } // find this, keywords have 'is'
  { name: 'hello world', keywords: ['hello', 'world'] } // don't find this, keywords don't match any words in name
```

How can I write the find sync in mongonDB or mongoose? Thanks.

Comment: you can try something like `var name = 'bar is good'; var nameArray = name.split(' ');` and `db.collection.find({"keywords":{$in:nameArray}})`

Comment: but the name string may not have space, maybe it is 'barisgood'

Comment: I don't think that is correct . How could you possibly match that string to keywords ?